# Django CMS menu, how to set a class to parents only?

Tags: css, django, menu, django-cms

My menu needs some work. I need to have a class on the parent menu items, but with my recursion, it is not working.

This is (part of) my menu:

```
Home
    Teachers (id teachers)
        Contact
        Info
        Projects
          myproject
          yourproject
```

I start with "teachers" like this:

```
{% show_menu_below_id "teqchers" 0 1 0 1 "teachers_menu.html" %}
```

And this is my teachers_menu.html:

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for child in children %} 
    <li class="{% if child.selected %}selected parent_{{forloop.counter}}{% endif %} {% if child.sibling %}parent_{{forloop.counter}} {% endif %}"> 
        <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
        {% if child.children %}
        <div class="submenu">   
            <ul>
                {% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

With this in place, my menu is working for a bit.

When i click Projects, all is well and the 2 projects are in view. But when i click a project, i expect the page to show, but it does not, it does rebuild my menu, and adds the needed class to the child elements:

```
{% if child.selected %}selected parent_{{forloop.counter}}{% endif %}
```

Obvious because it is a child now i guess, but how to prevent this? I only need that class for the first menu items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing this:

```
{% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active template "" "" child %}
```

I now added another template like this:

```
{% show_menu from_level to_level extra_inactive extra_active "teachers_submenu.html" "" "" child %}
```

And in that template I now have:

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% for child in children %} 
    <li class="{% if child.selected %}selected{% endif %}"> 
        <a href="{{ child.get_absolute_url }}">{{ child.get_menu_title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

So the extra template takes care of the submenu. With some styling it now works.