# CSS/JS - Remove Animating Link Underlines for one li element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, django

I got [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ma5n11v0/1/) code, with an animated link underline. This ul li is automatically generated by django `{% show_menu %}`.

I would like the animated link to be disabled for the third li element - the img with the attached logo class.

I have been trying out different solutions like this one:

```
a:hover .logo::before {
  display:none;
}
```

but can't seem to figure it out! Please see my code, and help me (:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the before is on the anchor and there is no parent selector in css for the logo.

I would use the `nth-child` or `nth-oftype` selector (as you have already used `nth-of-type` for the width of the logo cell, I would stick with using that):

```
#nav > ul > li:nth-of-type(3) a:hover:before {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma5n11v0/2/)

Just note, if you change your li structure, you will need to change your css so it isn't a very good solution if the nav is going to change a lot

Comment: Beautiful! That's it! Thank alot :D

Comment: Your welcome, if you want to make it a bit more able to handle the dynamic nav, then you might consider adding a class to the parent li: [check this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27232567/django-cms-menu-how-to-set-a-class-to-parents-only)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the li you don't want to animate, E.G.

```
<li class="noUnderline><a href="#">
```

and then exclude it from your css rule:

```
#nav > ul > li:not(.noUnderline) a:hover {

}
```

Comment: I think doing it this way may be better than using the nth-child method, as you could potentially add more li's in future which may mean it's not always going to be the third child.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **span** in the place of **anchor tag**. check with the below link.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma5n11v0/4/)

```
 <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li><span><img src="http://pre08.deviantart.net/ae58/th/pre/f/2012/120/5/9/thundercats_1985_2011_logo_by_pencilshade-d4y2uzr.png" alt="" class="logo" /></span></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">Menu 4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ma5n11v0/5/) out. Your anchor link is managed to stay clickable while animation is gone.

```
<div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a class="animate" href="index.html">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a class="animate" href="index.html">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><img src="http://pre08.deviantart.net/ae58/th/pre/f/2012/120/5/9/thundercats_1985_2011_logo_by_pencilshade-d4y2uzr.png" alt="" class="logo" /></a></li>
    <li><a class="animate" href="index.html">Menu 3</a></li>
    <li><a class="animate" href="index.html">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```